# Convert all elements of row to name of month and year

Tags: pandas, datetime, apply

I want to convert 4th row (index 3) to name of month and year

[image: df]

I have dataframe with one row containing dates. It is datetime.datetime object. I want to convert all elements of rows to name of month and year.

Comment: You should transpose your dataframe. Pandas datatypes are defined along the axis column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the row, manipulate it to extract year and month name, and replace:

```
datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[3])
month_year = datetime.apply(lambda x: x.month_name() + ", " + str(x.year))
df.iloc[3] = month_year
```

Comment: I used that code. And I had used similar code using apply method. I am getting this error.     datetime = pd.to_datetime(df_12.iloc[3])
month_year = datetime.apply(lambda x: x.month_name() + ", " + str(x.year))
df_12.iloc[3] = month_year

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: I converted the month name to string It was solved.

Comment: Great, then mark my answer as the solution!